# Kik bot raises "kik.error.KikError" error when used in a group, but works in 1 to 1 chat

Tags: python-3.x, api, bots, kik

I have created a test bot named pepememe.bot using the python library provided by kik. The bot works fine when I am chatting to it using private message.[image: pepememe.bot in a private message conversation]
But fails with the below error when I use it in my group.
[image: error screenshot]
    kik.error.KikError: {"message":"You are not allowed to send a message to this conversation","error":"Forbidden"}

A point to note is that it did work for sometime in my group, but suddenly started throwing that error. I have emailed Kik Bots Support about this, but they haven't replied back. What should I do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I see that your bot is not approved.
There is a 50 subscribers limit for unapproved bots, check if you are over the limit.
Also it is possible that Kik blocked access to group chats for unapproved bots.